# Finding the ancestors of a node in a binary tree with only the value of a node

Tags: c++, data-structures, binary-tree, ancestor

I am trying to finish a method which takes in a value, I have to RECURSIVELY find the the ancestors of a node with a matching value in a binary tree, so far I'm running into a little trouble with the recursive part, here's the class im working with:

```
#ifndef TREETYPE_H
#define TREETYPE_H
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include "QueType.h"
using namespace std;

enum OrderType {PRE_ORDER, IN_ORDER, POST_ORDER};

template<class ItemType>
struct TreeNode;

template <class ItemType>
class TreeType
{
public:
  TreeType();                     // constructor
 ~TreeType();                    // destructor
  TreeType(const TreeType<ItemType>& originalTree);
  void operator=(const TreeType<ItemType>& originalTree);
  // copy constructor
  void MakeEmpty();
  bool IsEmpty() const;
  bool IsFull() const;
  int GetLength() const; 
  ItemType GetItem(ItemType item, bool& found);
  void PutItem(ItemType item);
  void DeleteItem(ItemType item);
  void ResetTree(OrderType order); 
  ItemType GetNextItem(OrderType order, bool& finished);
  void Print(ofstream& outFile) const;
  string Ancestors(ItemType item) const;
  string AncestorsNext(TreeNode<ItemType>* node, ItemType item) const;
private:
  TreeNode<ItemType>* root;
  QueType<ItemType> preQue;
  QueType<ItemType> inQue;
  QueType<ItemType> postQue;
};

template <class ItemType>
struct TreeNode
{
  ItemType info;
  TreeNode* left;
  TreeNode* right;
};
```

And here's what I have so far with my ancestors method:

```
// This recursive function will return the ancestors of item in reverse order.
template <class ItemType>
string TreeType<ItemType>::Ancestors(ItemType item) const{
    string out="";
    TreeNode<ItemType>* temp=root;
    if(root==nullptr || root->info==item){
        return "Value has no ancestors";
    }
    else{

        if(temp->info>item){
            out+=temp->info;
            temp=temp->left;
            TreeType<ItemType>::Ancestors(temp->info);
        }
        if(temp->info<item){
            out+=temp->info;
            temp=temp->right;
            TreeType<ItemType>::Ancestors(temp->info);
        }
    }

    return out;

}
```

Im stuck on how I can use recursion to check the next value in the tree with my `temp` variable if it just gets set to root everytime. If there's another way im all ears!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I m stuck on how I can use recursion to check the next value in the tree with my temp variable if it just gets set to root everytime.

---

This is a common mistake with a simple solution.  (But maybe not if you can not add a method)

Essentially, you are trying to do too-many-things in one function.

The simple solution is to split your current function into 2 functions,

a) one that handles the initialization of where to start searching, which is not recursive,

b) and another that performs the recursion.

I hope the following provides enough hint for you (as I am not practiced with templates)

```
template <class ItemType>
string TreeType<ItemType>::Ancestors(ItemType item) const
{
    string out = AncestorsR(item, root)  // invoke recursive funct
    return out;
}

template <class ItemType>
string TreeType<ItemType>::AncestorsR(ItemType item,
                           TreeNode<ItemType>* temp) const
{
    string out="";

    if(temp==nullptr || temp->info==item)
    {
        return "Value has no ancestors";
    }
    else
    {
        if(temp->info>item)
        {
            out+=temp->info;
            temp=temp->left;
            TreeType<ItemType>::Ancestors(temp->info);
        }
        if(temp->info<item)
        {
            out+=temp->info;
            temp=temp->right;
            TreeType<ItemType>::Ancestors(temp->info);
        }
    }
    return out;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing a recursion, you can simply init temp=root as you did and then use a while loop:

```
while ( temp->left && temp->right && temp->info != item )
{
    if ( temp->info > item )
    {
        // your ancestor stuff
        temp = temp->left;
    }
    else if ( temp->info < item )
    {
        // your ancestor stuff
        temp = temp->right;
    }
}
```

Comment: I actually had it like this before, but the implementation must be recursive!

Comment: I don't see any reason to use a recursion if you've already solved the problem (an educational exercise ?). Anyway you can have your ancestor function taking the temp node as argument and do the same if/else if stuff inside but instead of doing temp = temp->left, you can call ancestor(temp->left) and use the return type to concatenate your output string from the left ans right recursive calls

Comment: Yea haha it is an educational exercise, unfortunately I am not allowed to change the parameters of the method or else I would do that.

Comment: xd. I see another alternative: if ItemType is an integer, you can reserve some bits to encode the node path from the root. 1=left, 0=right and you can also encode the recursion depth to know how many bits are readable. This requires to know the max possible depth 2^n in order to represent it with n bits + n bits for the left/right node path

Comment: ItemType is of type string, thank you for this very detailed explanation!

Answer (score 0):

> If there's another way im all ears!

Consider:

a) pass a "vector of TreeNodes" as a second parameter into your Ancestors() method.

b) During the recursive search (I used depth first) , use **push_back** into the vector to CAPTURE the visited ancestors (node*) during the search,

c) and when value is found, return the ancestor of interest.

d) When not found (in the current branch), use **pop_back** during the 'de-cursion' to remove unwanted ancestor node(s).

---

I used the technique to find the nodes which sum to a target.

Example output:  (search for nodes that sum to -5)

```
   BTree_t::dfVisitSum(-5)   
     @ level 3:    -2   -3 
     @ level 2:     0   -2   -3
```

In the tree:  (i.e. test input)

```
BTree_t::showTallView():  (balance: 0  sz: 19)

                -3 
           -2 
                -1 
       0 
                 1 
            2 
                      3 
                 4 
  5 
                 6 
            7 
                      8 
                 9 
      10 
                11 
           12 
                     13 
                14 
                     42
```

---

```
// target-sum-search
int Node_t::sumSearch(const int targetSum, NVec_t& nodeLog)
{
   int reportCount = 0;
   // diag only  std::cout << "  Node_t::sumSearch() " << m_payLoad << std::endl;

   // CAPTURE visit to log
   nodeLog.push_back(this); // trace node route (depth-first-search style)

   if(m_left)
   {
      reportCount += m_left->sumSearch(targetSum, nodeLog);  // RECURSE
   }

   {
      size_t   startLvl = nodeLog[0]->m_lvl; // used in report

      int accumulateSum = 0;
      for (size_t i = 0; i < nodeLog.size(); ++i)
         accumulateSum += nodeLog[i]->m_payLoad;

      if (targetSum == accumulateSum)
      {
         std::stringstream reportLabelSS;
         reportLabelSS << "\n     @ level " << startLvl << ":";
         std::cout << showNVec(nodeLog, reportLabelSS.str());
         reportCount += 1;
      }
   }

   if(m_right)
   {
      reportCount += m_right->sumSearch(targetSum, nodeLog);  // RECURSE
   }


   // REMOVE this node visit from log
   nodeLog.pop_back(); // removes last nodeLog element  // DE-CURSE

   return(reportCount); // report count
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot change the method parameters, thank you for this very detailed write up!